# How to resolve Haskell error in loading module?

Tags: haskell

I am getting the following error.

```
(base) Pauls-MBP-2:~ reiners$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Euterpea

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Euterpea’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
Prelude>
```

I had previously installed [Euterpea](http://euterpea.com/) with the command

```
cabal install Euterpea
```

In fact, the import actually worked.  However, for other reasons, I closed that command prompt, and now it's not working.

I also tried running it from the *cabal repl* and got the same result:

```
(base) Pauls-MBP-2:~ reiners$ cabal repl
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.8.4 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - fake-package-0 (lib) (first run)
Configuring library for fake-package-0..
Preprocessing library for fake-package-0..
Warning: No exposed modules
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /var/folders/8k/74p15mf15zsg82l4r7xz28t00000gn/T/cabal-repl.-19576/setcwd.ghci
Prelude> import Euterpia

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Euterpia’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
Prelude>
```

I'm using macOS Catalina (10.15.7).

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps if you used cabal to install it, you need to run GHCi using `cabal repl` to make that package available (?)

Comment: No, that gave the same results.

Comment: What version of cabal?